# How to convert time interval from PostgreSQL in java

Tags: java, postgresql, intervals

I want to select the `time_interval` column which is of type `interval` from PostgreSQL.

and convert to long type with Java code

my table is

```
  trigger
  id   time_interval  cdate 
  1     01:00:00      2018-12-11
  2     1 day         2018-12-11
  3     1 month       2018-12-11
  4     00:05:00      2018-12-11
```

The Java code is

```
   List<Long> results= executeQuery("select * from trigger limit 10",(rs,rowNum)->{

        Long time_interval = rs.getTimestamp("time_interval").getTime();

        return time_interval ;

    });
```

My error is

```
nested exception is
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Bad value for type timestamp/date/time: {1}
```

Comment: Intervals from Postgresql are not a supported format of Java, I've seen some people juggle between PG Intervals and Joda Time intervals which would probably be the closest to what you're looking for. Alternatively you could convert the interval to an epoch time stamp using `SELECT EXTRACT(epoch FROM l_interval)/3600`

Comment: Another option is to try `getString()` and create a smart parser that will distinguish between the formats and return you a value in the type you need.

Comment: It’s not trivial. The best class for representing the length of the time interval in Java is probably `PeriodDuration` of the [ThreeTen Extra](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project since Java doesn’t have an appropriate type built in. And as @coladict said, you would probably have to write your own parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the special type `org.postgresql.util.PGInterval` to handle PostgreSQL `interval`s:

```
org.postgresql.util.PGInterval i =
    (org.postgresql.util.PGInterval) rs.getObject("time_interval");

// gives something like "1 years 0 mons 0 days 2 hours 0 mins 0.00 secs"
System.out.println(i);

// gives something like "2"
System.out.println(i.getHours());
```

I don't know what `long` value you want to calculate from the interval, but if it is the length in milliseconds, you could proceed like this:

```
java.util.Calendar cal = new java.util.GregorianCalendar();
cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
i.add(cal);
System.out.println(cal.getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the interval as a long value anyway, you could convert the interval to a long in SQL:

```
select id, extract(epoch from time_interval) as time_interval, cdate 
from trigger;
```

Then you can use `ResultSet.getLong("time_interval")` to retrieve that value without the need to juggle with things that JDBC does not natively supports.